# Which graphs are zero-divisor graphs for some ring?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, graph-theory, co.combinatorics

Given a (non commutative) ring $R$, we construct a (directed) graph $G_0(R)$ with vertex set $Z(R)\backslash \{0\}$, the zero divisors of $R$ except for $0$. And an edge from $x$ to $y$ whenever $xy=0$. This is called the zero divisor graph of $R$.

My question is, what are the known obstructions to a graph being a zero divisor graph for some ring $R$?

---

(Edit) Following the reference by M. Sapir below, I found several articles which give partial answers. By this result of [Dolžan and Oblak](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.2470) we learn that there are restrictions on the diameter and girth (they work over semirings). In the case of commutative rings, one knows by a result of [Belshoff and Chapman](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869307003924), which zero-divisor graphs are planar, and there are similar results for [projective](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869307005716) zero-divisor graphs and other genera. Another restriction is that the number of edges must be even.

It seems that a characterisation of the set of zero-divisor graphs is open and complicated enough that is only worth studying over special subclasses of graphs. Because of this I would like to focus just on the second question below, which I have the feeling should have an easy counter-example.

---

I'd also like to ask the same question for a weaker notion of graphs associated to a ring. Let $G_{k}(R)$ be defined for every ring $R$ and $k\in R$ as above but with edges going from $x$ to $y$ whenever $xy=k$ (we can start with the vertex set being all of $R$ and then throw away the isolated vertices).

What graphs can be written as $G_k(R)$ for some pair $(R,k)$?

> Are there graphs which are isomorphic to $G_k(R)$ for some $k\neq 0$ but are not isomorphic to any zero divisor graph?

Comment: If you disallow the one-element ring, there are easy examples for G_k(R), including the two element ring.  So I conclude that the one-element ring is allowed.   Also, just to check, are loops (edges with one vertex) allowed? Gerhard "Let's Not Mention Empty Rings" Paseman, 2011.07.20 

Comment: I messed up the definition of the graph.  I apologize for the previous (erroneous) remarks and question.  Gerhard "Back To The Scratch Pad" Paseman, 2011.07.20 

Comment: For $\mathbb F_2$ one has $G_0(\mathbb F_2)=G_1(\mathbb F_2)=\emptyset$ according to the definitions above. I would like to have a generic counter-example with a number of vertices that is arbitrarily large, and have $G_k(R)$ connected. I'm going to allow loops for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the second question is "no". Consider first the case of semigroups. Take the bicyclic semigroup $B=\langle a,b \mid ab=1\rangle$. It consists of elements of the form $b^ma^n$, $m,n\ge 0$ (that representation is unique because $ab\to 1$ is a confluent and terminating rewriting system, see also A. H. Clifford and G. B. Preston, "The algebraic theory of semigroups" or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicyclic_semigroup). Take $k=1$. The corresponding graph consists of countably many disjoint edges $a^m\to b^m$, $m\ge 0$. Now suppose that this graph is the zero divisor graph of some semigroup $S$ with 0. Then it should have $p,q$ with $pq=0$. Since for every $x\in S$ we have $(xp)q=0$, we should have $xp\to q$ in the zero-divisor graph (the option  $xp=0$ does not occur because in our graph there are no edges $x\to p$). Hence $xp=p$ for every $x\ne 0\in S$. Similarly for every $x\ne 0\in S$ we have $qx=q$. Therefore $q=qp=p$, a contradiction. This argument works also for rings. One needs to consider the semigroup ring $FB$ for any field $F$, and take $k=1$. The corresponding graph is not the zero divisor graph of any (associative) ring.

In general if $R$ is a ring with 1 containing two elements $a,b$ such that $ab=1$ but $ba\ne 1$, and $a,b$ are not zero divisors, then the graph corresponding to 1 in $R$ is not a zero divisor graph of any ring $R'$. Indeed, in such a ring $R'$ we would have $ab=0, ba\ne 0$, and $xa=a, bx=b$ for every $x\ne 0$. Hence $a=ba=b$. The fact that $xa\ne 0$ (hence $xa=a$ in $R'$ is true because in $R$ we have $xa\ne 1$ for every $x$ (if $xa=1$, then $x=xab=b$, so $ba=1$, a contradiction). The fact that $xa=a$ is true because in $R$, $zb=1$ implies $z=a$ since $b$ is not a zero divisor. Similar for $bx=b$.

Comment: I like your answer. It is a lot simpler than my other idea of pairs of left and right ideals for the case k=0, which did not extend nicely to nonzero k.  Just as well I kept quiet about that.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.07.23

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to accept this answer. I just played around to convince myself that small variations of this really produce counterexamples under all sorts of requirements.

Answer (score 7):

See Akbari, S.; Mohammadian, A.
Zero-divisor graphs of non-commutative rings. 
J. Algebra 296 (2006), no. 2, 462–479, for example. The second question is answered below.

Comment: Thank you for this reference. At the moment I don't have access to the paper, but I can read from the abstract that one of their results is that they classify the rings for which the zero-divisor graph is a complete graph, a bipartite graph or a tree. Does their result imply which bipartite graphs or trees appear as zero-divisor graphs? If so, I'd appreciate it if you could add this information to the answer. +1

Comment: I have sent you the paper. 

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea which is not fully worked out.  At best, it is a refinement of Gjergji's refinement.  However, a negative answer would also answer Gjergji's question above, and on the other hand a construction might provide insight on building a zero divisor graph which is isomorphic to a graph for other kinds of nonzero k.

I am thinking in terms of semigroups, and have not checked that a ring will have this kind of multiplication.  One major difference between 0 and a nonzero k is that nilpotent x will have all powers greater than some power equal to 0; this does not always hold for nonzero k which is a power of some x.  In particular, if $x^{n+m}=x^n$ for some nonzero x and m > 1, there will be a subgraph of the graph for $x^n$ which will have at most one loop and a bunch of disjoint pairs of vertices with edges going in both directions between the members of the pair.  It might be arranged in the ring that k can only be a power of x, in which case there will be no edges in the graph for k other than among powers of x.  Now for the refinement:  Assuming a ring exists with $x$ not nilpotent, $k= x^j$ and satisfying $x^n=x^{n+m}$, with appropriate choices for integers j,n and m, can one build a different ring with zero divisor graph matching the graph for k in this ring?  I think choosing the integers mod q for some really large q will work for certain tuples of parameters j,n, and m, but I haven't checked all tuples.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.07.22

Comment: It is true that the case of semigroups is similar but easier than the case of rings, and one should start with semigroups. I would also first consider the case when $k=1$ (the identity element). Use the fact that in the bicyclic semigroup $\langle a,b\mid ab=1\rangle$, the product $ba$ is not 1. 